# ImageButton not responding

Tags: java, android, activitynotfoundexception

What I am attempting to do is to open "Items" when the `ImageButton` "ibItem1" is pressed. But, after setting up this:

```
ibItem1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent items = new Intent("android.intent.action.ITEMS");
            startActivity(items);
        }
    });
```

And clicking the button does not do anything. I have the activity all set up in the manifest:

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.example.custombuilds.Items"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ITEMS" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

The program has crashed before because of a `ActivityNotFoundException`, even though I declared it in the manifest.

Comment: Is `com.example.custombuilds.Items` extending from `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Also, for an intent action I would strongly disagree with this naming that you have: `android.intent.action.ITEMS` ... `android.intent.action.*` is reserved for Android actions. Imagine Android will add this action in a future release and it will break your app since you will not handle that action.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In this form, it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the name of the class that implements the activity is the same in the manifest file at the android:name="atributevalue".The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name.